# How to Redirect ReactJS contact Page to Thnak You Page after submitting the form

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

My ReactJS contact form is working fine and showing thank you message with Pop Up after submitting form details successfully.

But i want redirect user to ThankYou page instead of popup after submitting the form **successfully**. What changes will be required in this code to implement requirement -

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import axios from "axios";
import Swal from "sweetalert2";
import withReactContent from "sweetalert2-react-content";
import baseUrl from "../../utils/baseUrl";

const MySwal = withReactContent(Swal);
const alertContent = () => {
  MySwal.fire({
    title: "Congratulations!",
    text: "Your message was successfully send and will back to you soon",
    icon: "success",
    timer: 2000,
    timerProgressBar: true,
    showConfirmButton: false
  });
};

// Form initial state
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  name: "",
  email: "",
  number: "",
  subject: "",
  text: ""
};

const ContactForm = () => {
  const [contact, setContact] = useState(INITIAL_STATE);
  const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm();

  const popUpRef = useRef(null);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setContact((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, [name]: value }));
    console.log(contact);
  };

  
  const onSubmit = async (e) => {
    console.log("This is contact form")
    // e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const url = `${baseUrl}/api/contact`;
      const { name, email, number, subject, text } = contact;
      const payload = { name, email, number, subject, text };
      // const response = await axios.post(url, payload);
      await axios.post(url, payload);
      console.log(url);
      setContact(INITIAL_STATE);
      alertContent();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="contact-form">
      <form id="contactForm" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
            <div className="form-group">
              <input
                type="text"
                name="name"
                placeholder="Name"
                className="form-control"
                value={contact.name}
                onChange={handleChange}
                ref={register({ required: true })}
              />
              <div className="invalid-feedback" style={{ display: "block" }}>
                {errors.name && "Please enter your name"}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
            <div className="form-group">
              <input
                type="email"
                name="email"
                placeholder="Your work email"
                className="form-control"
                value={contact.email}
                onChange={handleChange}
                ref={register({ required: true, pattern: /^\S+@\S+$/i })}
              />
              <div className="invalid-feedback" style={{ display: "block" }}>
                {errors.email && "Please enter your email"}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
            <div className="form-group">
              <input
                type="text"
                name="number"
                placeholder="Phone"
                className="form-control"
                value={contact.number}
                onChange={handleChange}
                ref={register({ required: true })}
              />
              <div className="invalid-feedback" style={{ display: "block" }}>
                {errors.number && "Please enter your number"}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
            <div className="form-group">
              <input
                type="text"
                name="subject"
                placeholder="Subject"
                className="form-control"
                value={contact.subject}
                onChange={handleChange}
                ref={register({ required: true })}
              />
              <div className="invalid-feedback" style={{ display: "block" }}>
                {errors.subject && "Please enter your number"}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
            <div className="form-group">
              <textarea
                name="text"
                cols="30"
                rows="5"
                placeholder="Write your message..."
                className="form-control"
                value={contact.text}
                onChange={handleChange}
                ref={register({ required: true })}
              />
              <div className="invalid-feedback" style={{ display: "block" }}>
                {errors.text && "Write your message"}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
            
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            Send Message{" "}
            </button>
           
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ContactForm;
```

**Your valuable suggestions will be highly appreciable.**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ***"React Router"*** try this.

```
const {useNavigate} from "react-router-dom";

const navigate = useNavigate();

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // ... your existing form submission code with validations ...
    navigate('/thank-you'); // navigate to the thank you page
  };
```